# how to put boolean field in data table while working with jsf and managed bean?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

h:datatable question
here i have table with "isApprove" field..how to display its value. true or false? i want to display "corect" of "incorect" image according to the true or false value. how to do that? any 1 can help me?

```
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Company List" />
                </f:facet>
                <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{company.appCompanyName}"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                 <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="isApproved"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{company.isAppIsApproved}"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
And ManagedBean code is

...
public Boolean getIsApproved() {
        return isApproved;
    }

    public void setIsApproved(Boolean isApproved) {
        this.isApproved = isApproved;
    }

    public CompanyListManagedBean() {
    }

     public Collection<Tblcompany> GetCompanyList() {
        return showAllCompany();
    }

    private java.util.List<webservice.Tblcompany> showAllCompany() {
        webservice.AdminWebService port = service.getAdminWebServicePort();
        return port.showAllCompany();
    }
...
```

Comment: Note that your expression is incorrect. With the given getter method name `getIsApproved()`, you should be using `#{company.isApproved}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:graphicImage rendered="#{company.isAppIsApproved}" ... /> //correct image
<h:graphicImage rendered="#{not company.isAppIsApproved}" ... /> //incorrect image
```

I think it's pretty obvious from the code how it's work:-)Note that you can use it for almost all elements like `<h:table>`, `<h:panelGrid>`, `<h:form>` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:graphicImage id="correctImage" value="./myCorrectImage.png" rendered="#{company.isAppIsApproved}"/>
<h:graphicImage id="notCorrectImage" value="./myIncorrectImage.png" rendered="#{not company.isAppIsApproved}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, add a checkbox and using the `<a4j:support>` action we can change the images as desired in the bean's method or use `Graphic Image`

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Bean.isAppIsApproved}">
                                    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{Bean.approvedCheck}" reRender="tableId" />
                                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```